# How to fix Redis Performance Issues?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using C# client "StackExchange.Redis" for benchmarking Redis.
The dataset is a text file of close to 16 million records. Each record has six entries, three of which are double and the other three are integers.
When I use LPush (LPushRight in api), it takes close to 4 minutes for all the data be added to Redis. 
Afterwards, when I retrieve the data using (LRange in api), it takes almost 1.5 minutes to retrieve all the list.
I am using following code:

Connection:

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
```

Insertion:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines =
File.ReadLines(@"C:\Hep.xyz");
    List<string> linesList = lines.ToList();
    int count = lines.Count();
    string[] toks;
    RedisValue[] redisToks = { "", "", "", "", "", "" };
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
         toks = linesList[i].Split(' ', '\t');
         for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
         {
                redisToks[j] = toks[j];
         }
         db.ListRightPushAsync("PS:DATA:", redisToks);
         if (i % 1000000 == 0)
         {
              Console.WriteLine("Lines Read: {0}", i);
         }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue ...");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Retrieval:

```
long len  = db.ListLength("PS:DATA:");

long start = 0;
long end = 99999;
while (end < len)
{
      RedisValue[] val = db.ListRange("PS:DATA:", start, end);
      int length = val.Length;
      start += 100000;
      end += 100000;
}
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue ...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

For COnfiguration:

I have set **maxmemory** to **4GB** and **maxmemory-policy** to **volatile-lru**

I am running all that locally on my system. My system specs are
8 GB RAM
Inter Core i7 - 5500U CPU @ 2.4GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.4 GHz

Could you please help me identify the factors I need to look into, to improve performance. Also, is redis suitable for this kind of dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This is not caused by that redis is slow. Becuase when you save data into redis, the time cost also includes the file io (disk io) and network io, especially the time you read lines from disk files, which takes a big time cost. So you see when you retrieve data from redis, the time cost is just 1.5 minutes and when you do insertion it took about 4 minutes.

In conclusion, redis works well in your case. one more thing to speed up the insertion is that you can use redis pipeline to decrease the network transport time.

The async write is not like the pipeline. But you should notice that async write just does not block the client. however the pipeline is batch sending command and batch read reply. So it is different.

And see https://redis.io/topics/pipelining  **It's not just a matter of RTT** section. pipelining save redis server read() and write() time also.

Comment: But shouldnt redis keep it in memory? Why read it from disk? Isnt this the whole purpose of in memory storage? Also, I am using async calls to write data, isnt that pipelining?

Comment: Can you please hide complete path in ur reply above? I accidentally left it, now I have replaced it in my question too.

Comment: What I said it takes a lot of time to read file is your File.ReadLines operation. and about async with pipeline, my answer is updated.

Comment: Not really. If I comment, the listpush calls, it takes 30 seconds opposed to 4 minutes with redis listpush calls

Comment: And I also mentioned network IO. Because your case is bulk load . Cost 4 minutes is normal for redis performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you faced is the issue mentioned in Redis's official website's [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro):

> Redis lists are implemented via Linked Lists. This means that even if you have millions of elements inside a list, the operation of adding a new element in the head or in the tail of the list is performed in constant time. The speed of adding a new element with the LPUSH command to the head of a list with ten elements is the same as adding an element to the head of list with 10 million elements.

This is the reason why your insertion operation is very fast. The document further continues:

> What's the downside? Accessing an element by index is very fast in
>   lists implemented with an Array (constant time indexed access) and **not
>   so fast** in lists implemented by linked lists (where the operation
>   requires an amount of work proportional to the index of the accessed
>   element).

The document further suggest to use Sorted Sets if you want fast access:

> When fast access to the middle of a large collection of elements is important, there is a different data structure that can be used, called sorted sets. Sorted sets will be covered later in this tutorial.